# onmousedown - left or right?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, onmousedown

First of all, I am not looking for jQuery solution, just simple pure Javascript code, inside of an element.

Let's say we have following html code:

```
<select onmousedown=" ??? ">...</select>
```

I want a simple script inside of the element to show popup message `alert()` with information which button was pushed down and what is a relative position of the element to the document `<body>` - something like `offset()` in jQuery.

Comment: "*I'm not looking for a jQuery solution*"... \*puts jquery tag\* `:P`

Comment: @Šime Vidas :: which means I am looking for jquery alternative code :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a JavaScript function with some name and then call it on `onmousedown` event passing the `event` and `this` object which can be used inside the function.

HTML

```
<select onmousedown="onMouseDown(event, this)">...</select>
```

JS

```
function onMouseDown(e, obj){
   e = e || window.event; //window.event for IE

   alert("Keycode of key pressed: " + (e.keyCode || e.which));
   alert("Offset-X = " + obj.offsetLeft);
   alert("Offset-Y = " + obj.offsetTop);

}
```

If you plan to use jQuery then you can use this script

```
$('select').mousedown(function(e){
    alert("Keycode of key pressed: " + e.which);

    //Inside the handler this points to the select DOM element
    alert("Offset-X = " + $(this).offset().left);
    alert("Offset-Y = " + $(this).offset().top); 
});
```

**Update:**

If you want inline script then try this.

```
<select onmousedown="function(e, obj){ e = e || window.event;alert('Keycode of key pressed: ' + (e.keyCode || e.which));alert('Offset-X = ' + obj.offsetLeft);alert('Offset-Y = ' + obj.offsetTop);}(event, this);">...</select>
```

Comment: There is no need in this case to use `e || window.event` since you are passing `event` from the listener.

Comment: In IE it doesn't work so we have to access it using window.event.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli :: I need solution without using any new name for function, as I need this for a code that other partners will need to add to their existing pages, so to eliminate risk of function name and/or variables conflict(s), I need solution without assigning some names to function and/or global variables. And I really mean script **inside of an element**, so something that would replace `???` in the `<select onmousedown=" ??? ">...</select>` code.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli—you are mistaken. When you write `< ... onclick="fn(event)">` then in IE the identifier `event` resolves to `window.event` and that is what is passed to `fn()`. In Mozilla and other browsers, it resolves to the event object of the handler, so they too passes a reference to the related event.

Comment: @RobG - I am talking about IE7 and less. May be it works in IE8+

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: I think, that one can use `arguments[0]` instead of `event` as the parameter: `<select onmousedown="return onMouseDown.call(this, arguments[0]);">...</select>`. In the way the `this` parameter of `onMouseDown` will be set to the DOM of the current `<select>` and the `onMouseDown` function can return `false` to stop  default processing. One should only define `onMouseDown` function as `var onMouseDown = function (e) {};` because `function` don't support `this`, at least in the `strict` mode of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

MouseEvent.button has different values in different browsers

```
MouseEvent.button == 1// means left key in ie6~ie8
MouseEvent.button == 0// means left key in ie9&others
```

Comment: Just to make your day, in IE the "left" button is 1 for *mousedown* and *mouseup*, but 0 for *click*, *dblclick* and *contextmenu* events.

Answer (score 1):

`<select id="foo" onmousedown="mouseDown()">...</select>`

```
window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN)
window.onmousedown = mouseDown

function mouseDown(e)
{
  xPos = e.screenX;
  yPos = e.screenY;
  alert('onmousedown foo ' + ' x:' + xPos + ' y:'+ yPos);
}
```

**Edit**

`<select id="foo" onmousedown="function mouseDown(e){alert(MouseEvent.button + ' x:' + e.screenX + ' y:'+ e.screenY);}">...</select>`

Comment: :: I really mean script **inside of an element**, so something that would replace **???** in the `<select onmousedown=" ??? ">...</select>` code.

Comment: Just move the script into the onmousedown attribute then

Comment: :: I cannot assign any new names to function as well as cannot create new global variables. Your code also do not check witch button was pushed, if primary (left) or some other...

Comment: Again, Just move the script into the onmousedown attribute then

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

You might like to read this article before you go any further: [Javascript Madness: Mouse Events](https://www.unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html)

Clicks on a document dispatch a [MouseEvent object](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#event-type-click) that has lots of properties—e.g. [MouseEvent.button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#events-MouseEvent-button) tells you which mouse button was pressed, [MouseEvent.ctrlKey](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#events-MouseEvent-ctrlKey) tells you if the control key was pressed when the click occured.

Note that the buttons aren't really "left" and "right", since they can be changed by user preferences, what you want to know is whether it was the primary button (usually left but might be right or could be something totally different from some other pointing device) or the secondary button (usually right but again, could be anything).

Some play code:

```
<script>
function clickDetails(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var msg = [];

  for (var p in e) {
    msg.push(p + ': ' + e[p]);
  }
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = msg.join('<br>');
}
    
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('sp0').onmousedown = clickDetails;
}

</script>

<div>
  <span id="sp0">click me</span>
  <br>
  <span id="msg"></span>
</div>
```

#### Edit

Ah, what the hell:

```
<select onmousedown="alert('Button: ' + event.button
                         + '\nPosition: ' + this.offsetLeft 
                         + ',' + this.offsetTop);">
```

Comment: No id for element available, the code needs to be inside of the element, no new global variables, no new names for new functions.

Comment: Then put the code in the handler, the above is just to help you out. I'm not going to write your code for you.